# What are advantages of using instance methods of class methods as delegates instead of static class functions as delegates in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C-sharp and found this interesting and wonder if there are any benefits on the choice one takes.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you define the two approaches? I'm not sure how can you delegate (usually this means receiving events) to static functions.

Comment: Please don't use tags unrelated to your question. Nothing in your question suggests that [tag:javascript] is relevant. Also, as A. Chiesa said, it would improve your question markedly if you showed the two things you're asking about.

Comment: Some context / specific examples here would *really* help. I mean... the most obvious difference is that one conveys knowledge of a specific instance, which is *great* if the instance matters, and pointless if it doesn't... in which case both can be at "advantage" or "disadvantage" depending on the scenario; conversely, delegates to static delegates can be easier to cache and reuse, etc

Comment: If you're new to C#, I'd strongly recommend focussing on writing clear, understandable code rather than deciding to jump straight into minute, possibly non-existent, differences between approaches.

Comment: The only difference I see is that the first approach keeps a reference to the instance alive whereas the second does not.